# Is it possible to implement authentication on the instance of the browser scope?

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication

Is it possible to implement authentication that only available in the same instance of the browser. I mean when the user enters from another instance of the same browser, he'll be able to log in from a different account. And the both accounts will be logged in at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean an instances of browser windows or a different browsers?

Comment: Different instances of the same browser

Comment: Did you use Form authorization before?

Comment: @OneHalfTrackMindMan: Are you kidding !!!

Comment: So could you show an example of login page markup and code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

Forms authentication allows this. Take in account that you must open another browser window not the tab because usually authentication cookies shared between tabs in browser window.

if you use Login control on a login page set DisplayRememberMe property value to false. And use following code for redirecting from the login page: `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(LoginControl.UserName, false);` In that case authentication cookies will be stored in browser's process and will not be shared between multiple instances of the browser.

I'll try to explain how the Forms Authentication works if you still interesting to got answer.
Each time you open a protected page system checking for authentication cookie. If it doesn't exists system returns an not authorized response and redirect user to a login page. When user enter login and password Forms Authorization try to authenticate user with provided credentials. If credentials are valid then system generate authentication cookie and send it to client's browser. Then this cookie used for future requests. 
There are two ways how this cookie can be stored on the client's side:
The first one - when cookie is persisted on the client's hard drive. In this case this particular cookie uses each time user open this site's page. And this cookie is the same for each and every browser instance, so it's true that you can't open different browser instance with a different credentials.
But the second option is when authentication cookie doesn't persisted on client's hard drive but stored in browser's process. In that case you can open a lot browser windows for a different users.
As I mention above this two scenarios in ASP.NET can be achieved by supplying proper second parameter for FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie or FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage methods: true for persist cookie on a client's HDD and false for store cookie in browser's process.

By the way, you can open web site page with different credentials even when it use Windows Authentication. To achieve this you must start browser with a "Run as..." command and provide a different Windows credentials.

Comment: How is that? when I log in in an instance and open another instance then the second instance will be logged in. And when I log out from one of them, the other one will be logged off.

Comment: Try it in IE with Gmail and you'll find it shares the authentication cookie cross the instances. I tried it also, same result (the authentication cookie is shared (IE 8,9) even when I tried (File - New Session))

Comment: Gmail store the cookie as persistent.  If you shut your computer down and start it back up you are still logged in.

Comment: @user748910: This is true only in case you've chosen _Stay online_. else, it'll log out when the browser is closed and then reopened. Try it!

Comment: Are you trying to build your own website or log onto two different gmail accounts simultaneously?

Comment: My own web application, but I mentioned the Gmail as a sample

Comment: You won't be able to test this using web sites like gmail because it will depend on how the particular web page stores their cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to do it keeping a session ID in the query string. This is very ugly, but possible (iirc) with Forms Authentication. Unless there is a very good specific reason for needing this, I'd recommend against this